# Help With PulledPork Please

Tags: networking, security, snort

I have been working to get snort, barnyard2 and pulledpork installed on my Ubuntu machine, and I have the 1st two installed not problem. With pulledpork I cant seem to get past this error message:

```
name@host:~/snort_src/pulledpork-0.7.0$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pulledpork.pl -c /etc/snort/pulledpork.conf -l 
http://code.google.com/p/pulledpork/
  _____ ____
 `----,\    )
  `--==\\  /    PulledPork v0.7.0 - Swine Flu!
   `--==\\/
 .-~~~~-.Y|\\_  Copyright (C) 2009-2013 JJ Cummings
      /  66\_  cummingsj@gmail.com
|    \   \   _(")
 \   /-| ||'--'  Rules give me wings!

Checking latest MD5 for snortrules-snapshot-2980.tar.gz....
    Error 422 when fetching https://www.snort.org/reg-rules/snortrules-snapshot-2980.tar.gz.md5 at /usr/local/bin/pulledpork.pl line 463.
    main::md5file('<oinkcode>', 'snortrules-snapshot-2980.tar.gz', '/tmp/', 'https://www.snort.org/reg-rules/') called at /usr/local/bin/pulledpork.pl line 1847
```

Comment: Looks like you ran into [Issue 164 - Cannot get rules as Snort registered user](https://code.google.com/p/pulledpork/issues/detail?id=164)

Comment: Or perhaps [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/snort/mailman/message/34662875/) will shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally....there is a naming issue with the way that pulledpork is getting the files from the snort site. The newest version of snort is 2.9.8.0 so when pulledpork tries to get the rules file with that name, it doesn't exist on the snort site. So, in my pulledpork.conf I set my snort_version to 2.9.7.6 which has a valid set of rules on the snort site. I also commented out the community rules because the naming there was also causing a similar issue I could not resolve.